# jQuery UI Tab Selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a jQuery UI tab inside a jQuery UI Modal popup. The tab is data driven with an ajax call to a service. Ther are 4 tabs but sometimes there is no data for the firs tab depending on user selection. If there is no data for the first tab I hide the first tab and select the second tab (alsways data for second tab). If there is data for the first tab I show it and select it. The hiding and showing works just fine. The selection works to a point. The popup containing the tab is fired by selection of data from a table that contains search results - the popup displays deatil information of the selection. If the users select first a tab that has data for the first tab - all is well. If the user then select data from the table tha that does not all is still well (first tab hidden - second tab selected). If the user then selecst some other data that contains data for the first tab - the first tab is shown and selected but - now the second tab is also still highlighted. The jQuery to select the first tab is like this: `$("#tabs").tabs('select', 0);` and for the second tab this: `$("#tabs").tabs('select', 1);`

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something to more clearly illustrate the problem?

Comment: Never used fiddle before - about to leave for the evening and will see if I can figure it out tonight and post more code. My whole issues center around the selection of a different tab and a previously selected tab still being highlighted.